# Exposing Interfaces for Handling Active MQ Events

Tags: java, api, interface, event-handling, activemq-classic

I have an application written in Java, which functions by communicating over ActiveMQ.
I have simple consumer and producer implemented in Java which are receiving and sending messages to a particular platform via Active MQ.

I need to provide interfaces to a third party for each defined event, so that they can implement a particular interface to perform a particular task on a particular event.
I am looking into different types of interfaces, i need to know that if Tag Interfaces can be some help in this case, if not then what technique should i use to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see that a [tag interface](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=240_) makes sense here.  It sounds like you want to throw events and have an observer *do something* which would be the [observer pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html).  Your interface cannot be empty because it must be able to throw all of the events you plan on generating.  There should be some internal code that uses this interface and throws events on each listener.

For example:

**The Listener:** The listener class holds all possible events.

**Ex. FlipListener:** Listens for coin flips.

```
public interface FlipListener{
    public void flip(final boolean heads);
}
```

**Generator of Events:** Notifies all listeners of each event.

**Ex. Coin:** Keeps a list of `FlipListener`'s and calls the `flip` method every time there is a coin flip.

```
public abstract class Coin {
    private final ArrayList<FlipListener> listeners = 
        new ArrayList<FlipListener>();

    public void addFlipListener(final FlipListener listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public boolean flipCoin(){
        final boolean isHeads = doFlip();
        for(final FlipListener listener : listeners)
            listener.flip(isHeads);

        return isHeads;
    }

    /**
     * Perform the actual coin flip and return the results: 
     * true if heads and false is tails.
     */
    protected abstract boolean doFlip();
}
```

**Listener Implementation:** Does something with the knowledge of events.

**Ex. StatsListener:** Keeps stats by listening for coin flip events.

```
public class StatsListener implements FlipListener{
    private int heads = 0;
    private int tails = 0;

    public int heads(){
        return heads;
    }

    public int tails(){
        return tails;
    }

    public void flip(final boolean isHeads){
        if(isHeads)
            ++heads;
        else
            ++tails;
    }
}
```